# Error getting pip version after install on Mac OS Yosemite

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I have python2.7.6 installed on mac, also pip. But when trying to get pip version or run it,  it has error.

Here is output from my mac:

```
$ which python

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

$ which pip

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip

$ python -V

Python 2.7.6

$ pip --version

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2793, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 673, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.3.1
```

Any idea?

Comment: What does `python -m pip --version`  and `echo $PYTHONPATH` print?

Comment: If you specifically don't need pip==1.3.1, are you able to run `pip install --upgrade pip`?

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening because you have the Mac OSX python intact but you have removed the Python folder from library . Just set the path in ~/.bash_profile for Mac OSX python and it will be resolved.